# Problem using grids - centering text and using gaps

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am learning to use grids in a website and have a couple of problems:

**I can't center the text in grid items;**

**If I attempt to have a gap between columns it only gets inserted between the last 2 columns.**

Is it possible that they are both due to the same error? I've tried margin-auto and various align and justify settings and none helped.

```css
.wrapper1 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
    gap: 10px;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(20px, auto);
}

.wrapper1 a {
    color: white;
}

.one {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 1;
    background-color: red;
}

.two {
    grid-column: 2 / 2;
    grid-row: 1;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper1">
    <div class="one"><a href="/chart/world-vaccinations-map">World Vaccinations</a></div>
    <div class="two"><a href="/chart/world-capita-new-cases-map">World Cases</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @tacoshy gap is a property. see the [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap)

Comment: That is not correct @tacoshy, `grid-gap` was renamed to `gap` with all the other `grid-` prefix properties https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap

Comment: Does `text-align:center` not work?

Comment: @patricaW there are only 2 columns of course the gap only gets put in between the 2 columns.

Comment: @tacoshy grid-row:1 is also valid among with gap

Comment: `gap` and `column-gap` is a valid property for grids also grid-gap is obsolete.

Comment: @bobsfriend - I included an example with just 2 columns but the problem happens with more columns (for example 6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine: Try below code, Have made basic additions. Basically you only have 2 columns set by `grid-template-columns: repeat(2 ,minmax(0, 1fr));`. Simply used `text-align:center` on the grid-container `.wrapper-1`. Rest all works as expected !!!

**UPDATE:** For any number of equal sizes columns below code snippet using CSS-Grids:

```css
a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
}
.wrapper1{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(6,1fr);
  gap:10px;
}

.wrapper1 div{
  background:red;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper1">
<div class="one"><a href="/one">One</a></div>

<div class="two"><a href="/two">Two</a></div>

<div class="three"><a href="/three">Three</a></div>

<div class="four"><a href="/four">Four</a></div>

<div class="five"><a href="five">Five</a></div>

<div class="six"><a href="six">Six</a></div>

</div>
```

Comment: yes, I was trying in codepen and it was working just fine. I would try to clear cache etc.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with 6 columns and it doesn't work. The first 3 columns do not display and there is a gap between column 5 and 6. I'll open a new question.

Comment: let me check :) You will probably have to use  grid-template-columns: repeat(6 ,minmax(fit-content, 1fr));

Comment: Thanks for checking. That resulted in one red row with empty cols 1 - 4, gap, col 5, gap, col 6

Comment: I've uploaded my code to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/PatriciaW/xnp48ke2/3/

Comment: Dear @PatriciaW : I think you are looking for this. Please check the link :-) https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/jOMRLYK Do let me know if there is anything else you are trying to achieve :-) HAPPY CODING

Comment: Wonderful ... that did it. I think the main changes you made were to move the text center and color to a new div definition and remove all of the css definitions for the columns. Much simpler. Many thanks.

Comment: Given that your solution is part of a private conversation is there any way to make it public?

Comment: I didn't get your question actually :-) The solution is public to everyone already. However this question has been closed :-) But still the question is public and people can still benefit from it :-) I have actually updated the answer to add the latest changes !!!

Comment: I removed the class="one" etc. since there weren't any class definitions for .one etc. That simplified it even more. Thanks